# A 2d image of all possible rgb colors

Tags: color

I've been searching for an image that contains all possible rbg colors, but I simply cannot find one. I'm starting to think that's it's impossible, since what I'm looking requires 3 dimensions.

I tried looking for things like "color wheel" or "hsv color" but I have been unable to find exactly what I'm looking for.

Is it even feasible to try to find a 2d image to represent a full rgb color scheme? And if yes, where can I find one?

To be explicit, I want a 2d image containing all (rgb) values (0-255, 0-255, 0-255)

Comment: ;) http://www.uwgb.edu/heuerc/2d/Color_circle_(hue-sat).png

Comment: a cool related project is http://allrgb.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 16,777,216 (256^3) possible RGB color combinations, so a square image in which each color is assigned a single pixel would have dimensions of 4096 px by 4096 px.

The following [Processing](https://www.processing.org/) code will generate such an image:

```
int numLevels = 256; // Number of levels per color channel
int numChannels = 3;

int dim = (int)sqrt(pow(numLevels, numChannels)); 
int curX = 0, curY = 0;
color curColor;

void setup(){
  size(dim, dim);
  colorMode(RGB);
  noLoop();
}

void draw(){

  for (int rVal = 0; rVal < numLevels; rVal++){
    for (int gVal = 0; gVal < numLevels; gVal++){
      for (int bVal = 0; bVal < numLevels; bVal++){
        curColor = color(rVal, gVal, bVal);
        set(curX, curY, curColor);
        curX++;
        if (curX >= dim){
          curX = 0;
          curY++;          
        }
      }  
    }    
  }

  save("rgb_colors.tif");

}
```

Most operating systems won't allow Processing to create a window large enough to display the entire image, but the full-size image will be saved as `rgb_colors.tif` and placed in the same directory as the script.

Comment: Change the value of `numLevels` and alter the `colorMode()` call such that the optional `max` argument is set to 2 to the power of the number of bits.

Comment: (My comment above was added in response to a comment/question from joojaa about how to handle different bit depths; I suppose it must have been deleted since then. At any rate, for regular 8-bit RGB my comment above can be ignored.)